Can 恋心 be platonic?
I think 恋 is for romantic love and not sure if in this 恋心 form it could be a general word for love of all people and not just romance

I would imagine not, because of the difference between 恋 and 愛, but I'm not sure so I'll just leave this as a comment.

恋心 is "romantic feeling" or "crush", and it never refers to familial love or such.
